# How to pickle/unpickle subclass of Keras efficiently for parallel processing?

Tags: keras, serialization, dask, distributed-computing, hpc

I am using Dask to distribute embarrassingly parallel deep learning Keras workloads.
In my case, the TCP protocol byte streams include pickled Keras objects. More specifically, I have a subclass of keras.engine.training.Model (with no custom layers), that takes more than 20s to deserialize (possible to see in dask's dashboard).

Note: I have not changed the serialization/deserialization configs of Dask. It is all default.

Main question: What can I do to improve the serialization/deserialization process of custom Keras subclassed models?
Side question 1: Is it possible to implement a more specific and efficient serializer/deserializer for my custom models and force dask to use them?
Side question 2: Is it possible to import my custom Keras class from all workers immediately when they launch and then pass arguments to construct the objects rather than pass the pickled objects?

Edit: I was checking the source code of Keras, and I see that they implement the **reduce** method for keras models. They use serialize_model_as_bytecode, deserialize_model_from_bytecode, implemented in keras.pickle_utils.
I understand that by overwriting the **reduce** functions in my custom model class will make me able to change dask's pickling process.